# How can I create a private cloud?

Tags: cloud

How can I create a private cloud computing environment using ubuntu; I have installed ubuntu desktop and tried converting to ubuntu-server.

What commands or steps that i need to follow to setup a basic version of cloud computing that can be exposed to external users (internet)