# How can I create private cloud?

Tags: cloud

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I create a private cloud?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58261/how-can-i-create-a-private-cloud)

How to create private cloud using Ubuntu 12.04?

How to install cloud and node controller and what basic steps are required?

Comment: **Please do not create duplicate questions about the same issue. Edit your existing question with any additional information. This makes it easier for people who want to *help* you out :).** Thanks and welcome to Ask Ubuntu!