# How to create a personal cloud using Eucalyptus?

Tags: server, cloud

I want to implement my own cloud and one of my friend told me that this can be done very easily on Ubuntu using Eucalyptus. Can anyone tell me how?

Comment: while not an answer that addresses eucalyptus specifically, check out these similar questions: http://askubuntu.com/questions/3678/make-my-own-dropbox-ubuntu-one-server-at-home and http://askubuntu.com/questions/58261/how-can-i-create-a-private-cloud

Comment: Have you already taken a look at the [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEC)? By the way, as the page says, there's also [OpenStack](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuCloudInfrastructure) which is being more and more used nowadays.

Comment: And before starting: are you 100% sure that you have enough resources to run a private cloud? If you just want your files to be accessible on the Web, a Web server is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eucalyptus_%28computing%29), Eucalyptus is an infrastructure to provide cloud services with a computer cluster. That means that Eucalyptus is a quite large and complex system that is meant to be run on a cluster of several or many computers. An Eucalyptus installation is comprised of (at least) 5 or 6 different components, like a cluster controller, a storage controller, a node controller and so forth. It is recommended that each of this component is run on its own machine.

From the impression I get of your plans, Eucalyptus might be way to large for what you want to do. You maybe want to look into [ownCloud](http://owncloud.org/) instead.

Comment: How do you know he doesn't have a computer cluster?

@"Vaibhav Gautam" - do you have a computer cluster? Are you aware of the scale of this thing?

Comment: As I said, "from the impression I get" ;) Of course it's only a guess on my part, but somebody who has the knowledge and experience of managing a server cluster in most cases knows how to find information about a system like Eucalyptus himself. So I'd assume he doesn't have that experience and doesn't know what he would get himself into, and I recommended a more feasable alternative.